# Ionic capacitor using passport for social login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I develped a website by react js and node js, and I transformed it into mobile version by capacitor.
But my android app is working in a way I didn't intend when login.
I used social login using passport in node js.
If I push the login button, google or facebook's login page pops up correctly, but if I login, a website I developed is popped on the browser app, not in my app.
How can I see my loggined page in my app?

I wrote node js code for login. I used passport library and make social login.
If login process is done, my node js sends res.render(page, {...}). And then the page is displayed on the browser app.
My capacitor.config.json looks like this.

```
{
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "dist",
  "cordova": {},
  "server": {
        "cleartext": true,
        "url": "correctUrl"
  },
  "android": {
        "allowMixedContent": true,
        "appendUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 Google"
  }
```

I know there is a way to build login using ionic library and ionic components in react js.
But is there any way to solve the problem without programming another login process?
I don't want to make mobile version and website version seperately since it's hard to maintain.
Is there any way to fix this with minimum code fix?